# Adding multiple services of same type to Ambari

Tags: apache-kafka, ambari

I am using Ambari to manage my Kafka cluster. I want to create another cluster which uses the same zookeeper of the previous cluster but is independent otherwise. I want to use the same Ambari service(UI) for this new one also. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to define a host config group in Ambari, such that a subset of hosts share similar configurations (such as a different ZK chroot for individual Kafka clusters), however, for any operation like service restarts and general display on the Kafka service page, different host groups would not be divided apart

In my experience, the host group feature has only been used for when some HDFS nodes have more disks attached, or more memory than others, so YARN and MapReduce settings were increased.

If you really need multiple isolated clusters, that's where external configuration management comes into play

Comment: So, you are configuring many zookeepers servers with the same external configuration management.  Just for curiosity, that external configuration should be another zookeeper cluster? Like a master node configuration?

Comment: The OP wanted to keep one ZK cluster. Ambari doesn't handle multiple ZK clusters that well because other services like HDFS, Hive, and HBase use interpolated values for their quorums. By external management, I meant like Ansible, Chef, Puppet, etc